# equivalent \addlinespace command for table columns?

Tags: tables, spacing

I just discovered the Latex command `\addlinespace` which increases the whitespace between the rows in a table. I was wondering if there is a command like that to increase the whitespace between the columns?

Comment: For this you could (should) define a new column type. So, `\usepackage{array}\newcolumntype{R}{@{\hspace{\dimexpr2\tabcolsep+3pt}}r}` and then `\begin{tabular}{rRRRR}`. Try it.

Answer (score 2):

Whether to be applied to one table:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begingroup\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{3mm}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\addlinespace{3mm}
a & b & c
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Whether to be applied globally:

```
\documentclass{article}

\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{3mm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\addlinespace{3mm}
a & b & c
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```